# AWS CloudFormation Lambda module sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to develop two serverless lambda functions that share some common module.
How can I describe this in the CloudFormation template?

desired folders structure:

```
src/
    lambda1
    lambda2
    module
```

desired template syntax:

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
    CodeUri: ./src/lambda1
```

this syntax doesn't include the module code into the deployment of the lambda and therefore I get a
**Runtime.ImportModuleError:**

Other discarded options are:

*option.1*

```
Properties:
    CodeUri: ./src/
```

but this includes the code of both lambda1 and lambda2 into the deployment of lambda1

*option.2*

duplicate the folder of module into both lambda1 and lambda2,
but this duplicates the code

What is best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> What is best approach to achieve this?

Use lambda [layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). In CloudFomration this is [AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-layerversion.html).